# What is the word for the order of succession in which son assumes the throne after father?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

It can be any son-younger son after elder son after father. Also, what can be the term for only a single family in power? Please answer.

Comment: *Primogeniture* is the term for succession passing from father to first-born son.
*Dynasty* denotes rule by one family; monarchy denotes King or Queen status upon said dynasty.

Dynasty can refer to Monarchy or Imperial succession, or to less legalistic structures like socially prominent families, by way of industry or finance or commerce, or even crime families... or sometimes politically-prominent families will have this term used to describe them.

Answer (score 1):

From [M-W:  patrilineal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patrilineal):
relating to, based on, or tracing descent through the paternal line.

A Dynastic monarchy would be rule by one family.

Comment: To the moderators:  Sorry, I wasn't aware of length requirements.  It does include a citation, but if it is that bad, please remove it.  I'll somehow get over it.